# Backbone route not invoking an action with URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backbone.js, pushstate

This is the code to a simple ToDo app using ASP.NET MVC:

```
 var Appointment = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function () {
            return {
                'date': new Date(),
                'cancelled': false,
                'title': 'Checkup'
            }
        }
    });

    var AppointmentList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Appointment,
        url:"/Home/Appointments"
    });

    var AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template('<span class="<% if(cancelled) print("cancelled") %>"><%= title %></span><a href="Home/Appointment/<%= id %>">x</a>'),

        initialize: function () {
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    var AppointmentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
        },
        addOne: function (model) {
            var appointmentView = new AppointmentView({ model: model });
            appointmentView.render();
            this.$el.append(appointmentView.el);
        }
    });


    var AppRouter = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: { "Home/Appointment/:id": "show", "": "index" },

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.appointmentList = new AppointmentList();
        },

        start: function () {
            Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
        },

        index: function () {
            var appointmentsView = new AppointmentListView({ collection: this.appointmentList });
            appointmentsView.render();
            $('body').html(appointmentsView.el);
            this.appointmentList.fetch();
        },

        show: function (id) {
            debugger;
            var appointment = new Appointment({ id: id });
            var appointmentView = new AppointmentView({ model: appointment });
            appointmentView.render();
            $('body').html(appointmentView.el);
            appointment.fetch();
        }
    }));

    $(function () { AppRouter.start() });
```

Please do not be overwhelmed by the code. If you look closely it is very simple as I am a noob.
My problem is that `show` action is not being hit. But `index` can works and can populate the page with view. I tried with all kinds of url to hit the `show` function but unsuccessful. Can someone please tell me what I need to do to make this right?

Comment: Is your server configured to use `{pushState:true}`?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I did not configure anything explicitly. Could you please tell me how I can ensure whether `pushState` is enabled on the server side (ASP.NET MVC 4) please?

Comment: The basic structure works (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tP9ZU/, no pushState at jsfiddle though).

Comment: As mu demonstrated - your code works, without `pushState`. You may want to read about [pushState](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

Comment: Yes. I just tested and it does work without `pushState` but then I cannot map to my `controller/action` properly because there is a `#` sticking out. Any solution for that?

Comment: @muistooshort and @fbynite Thanks it works now as intended without `pushState` but what if I wanted it enabled and working?